# Flutter: Display overlay even though route is changed by user action

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Consider I have two views, Orders view and Order Details view.

I would like to display an overlay (small section at the bottom) on Orders view, and when user selects an Order, we display Details view, but I want to continue to show the overlay, I want push route change so the back button etc work.

Is this doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `showModalBottomSheet`
more examples: [modal_bottom_sheet_demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/modal_bottom_sheet_demo.dart) [persistent_bottom_sheet_demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/persistent_bottom_sheet_demo.dart)

exam:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Modal bottom sheet'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'This is the modal bottom sheet. Tap anywhere to dismiss.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor, fontSize: 24.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I want to display the overlay in a minimized form, bottomsheet doens't support that feature currently

Comment: thanks, also with the help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341090/flutter-bottom-sheet-how-to-change-height-when-user-interacts-with-the-sheet/54342179#54342179 I was able to adjust the height of the bottom sheet accordingly. You still need to tweak the back button action accordingly.