# Flutter Bottom Sheet: How to change height when user interacts with the sheet

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In my flutter application I have a bottom sheet which gets shown with some initial height say 100. I would like to increase the height of the sheet (say may be 500 or go full screen) when user interacts with it (may be a gesture detection or clicking on a button on the sheet)

Is it possible to change the height of the sheet after it is loaded.

My bottomsheet is something like

```
  Widget _bottomSheetContainer(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border:
                Border(top: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor))),
        child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
            child:  Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text('Some text here!'),
            )
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                // color: themeData.primaryColor,
                onPressed: () => _onPressed(context)
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  _onPressed(BuildContext context) {
    BottomSheet w = context.widget;
    // Can we change the container height (from 100 to 500) that's part of the bottom sheet from here?

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make sure your widget is [stateful widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), then you can update it's instance parameters using `setState(() => ...)`, and flutter will update the rendered results.

```
class _WidgetState extends State<Widget> {
  double height = 200.0; // starting height value

  Widget build() { 
    <...>
    Container(
        height: height,
    <...>
  }

  _onPressed(BuildContext context) {
      BottomSheet w = context.widget;
      // Can we change the container height (from 100 to 500) that's part of the bottom sheet from here?
      setState({
        height = 300.0; // new height value
      })
  }

}
```